# Получить ссылку и заголовок прямой трансляции с инстаграма. PHP

Tags: php, instagram

День добрый.
Идея такая. Предаешь скрипту имя(ид или ссылку) пользователя, в ответ получаешь ссылку на видео-трансляцию и заголовок видео.

Пробовал разными способами получать медиа со страницы, но трансляции в списке нет.

Как можно решить задачу?

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/developer/ их api пользовались?

Comment: да. именно так я и получал информацию о странице и медиа.
"https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{$user_id}?access_token={$token}"